# Acrobat javascript document level function called from action

Tags: javascript, function, document, acrobat

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have searched everywhere but cannot find the answers. I want to create a function that can be used by field actions. So I created a function at the document level and then in the field action, I called the action. I get an error that says the function that is at the document level is undefined. I want to use one function many times via actions.

When I blue the field the debugger says TypeError: calculate in not a function

```
/*********** belongs to: Document-Level:calculate ***********/

function calculate() {

app.alert('working');

}

/*********** belongs to: AcroForm:Number of Payments:Annot1:OnBlur:Action1 ***********/

calculate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "calculate" is reserved in Acrobat and that's not documented for some reason. If you name your function anything else... like "calc"... it works.